# How to add text watermark to image using PHP

Tags: php, watermark

here i am doing multiple image upload , user select the images and click the submit button means i want  add watermark in that images after that i have to move the images in temporary folder,except adding water into the image i have completed, i don't know i how to add water mark in image , if anyone know means please update my answer

```js
 $("#rentBtnSubmit").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData();
   var formData = new FormData($('#rentForm')[0]);
   formData.append('file[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
     url :"test.php",
     data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
     if(data['status'] =='success'){
       alert('Success');
                     }
                     else{
       alert('Error');
                     } 
       },
    error:function(exception){
    $("#rentError").show(); 
   $("#rentError").fadeOut(4000); 
   }
   }); 
   });
```

```html
<form id="rentForm">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">Upload Property Photo</label>
   <br>
   <div id="maindiv">
   <div id="formdiv">
   <span id="filediv col-md-3"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file" multiple=""/></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
</div><br><br>
<button type="button center-block"  id="rentBtnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> test.php

```
    $FilleAll = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileCount = count($FilleAll);
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($FilleAll); $i++) {
    $extension = pathinfo( basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image_filename= md5(basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]).time()).'.'.$extension;
    $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],"watermark_images/".$image_filename);
}
```

Comment: Look into ImageMagick and get back to us.

Comment: You can look into `imagecreatefrompng`(if png)  `imagecopy` and `imagepng` on php

Comment: I tried lot but i am not able understand can you please update my code